# Android layout - view won't fill_parent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-view

I m trying to make a simple listitem layout.

My xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#ECEBE7">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rankView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#5C5C5C">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="1000"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/search" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/songView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rankView"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="song"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="artist"
        android:textColor="#90000000" />
</RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunatly, the rankView view is only matching it's content (height, not width), i've tryed every possibility I know and can't digure out why.

PS: On the graphical layout it's filling it's parent well.

EDIT: If it can help, the first layout is an item of the listView2 item of this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ECEBE7" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="Internet access is requiered to access the Top"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topText"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topText"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#5C5C5C"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Top 100 for"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="visible" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're setting the static 40dp width on rankView, it won't fill its parent as you explicitly set it. All the content inside it will be fit to that 40dp width.

Comment: @NKN Sorry, I forgot to mention I would like it to fill its parent in height, not width

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#ECEBE7">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rankView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#5C5C5C">
```

Try this.

Comment: use "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent" , as "fill_parent" is already depreciated in API level 8 or above.

Comment: I cannot because I need it to be 40dp in width

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT here you can see "FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
" so its always better to use whats latest.

Comment: @Tobor it is deprecated. fill_parent (renamed match_parent in API Level 8) tells your view to become as big as its parent view group will allow.

Comment: @Tobor Quoting `fill_parent` (renamed match_parent in API Level 8) tells your view to become as big as its parent view group will allow. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. so should be using `match_parent` above 8 and mostly you will be developing for above 8

Comment: @Raghunandan & Tobor Guys, Let's concentrate on user3119384's problem. If you'd like to discuss ' fill_parent ', take it to the Chat! :)

Comment: @Paramone its a correct suggestion so its not a discussion since its directly not an answer its in comment section

Comment: @Raghunandan If you really think so, Edit my post and put a note below it.

Comment: @Paramone i don't see op using `fill_parent` so i deleted my edit. You make the correction in your post

Comment: @Raghunandan You could still edit it if you'd like to. Incase op wants to use the code I've written. - But I get your point. Thanks for telling me anyway, Didn't realise it was depreciated

Comment: @Paramone Thanks for the try but it's the same result as my code :/ 

I ve added the code of the layout containing the listview containing the first layout items